# Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘Ex.catch’

Tags: haskell, exception

I've been fiddling about with Haskell, trying to understand error handling. While doing so I'm trying to come to grips with how to read and understand the ouput from GHC so I can better debug type errors.

I've written the following test:

```
import System.Environment
import qualified Control.Exception as Ex

getNum :: Int -> Int
getNum i = (!!) [1,2,3,4] i

outNum :: Int -> IO()
outNum i = Ex.catch (putStrLn(show (getNum i))) (\err -> putStrLn (show err))

main = do
   args <- getArgs
   outNum 3
```

This provokes the following error:

> Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘Ex.catch’ prevents
>   the constraint ‘(Ex.Exception a0)’ from being solved.

Looking at the definition of the functions involved:

```
catch :: IO a -> (IOError -> IO a) -> IO a
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
show :: Show a => a -> String
error :: [Char] -> a
```

I'm looking at this and thinking, the type of `a` must be `()` (unit type). What have I misunderstood, and how should Iamend my example so that it catches the exception and shows the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GHC doesn't know why type of exception you want to catch.

For instance, this version of outNum will catch any IOException:

```
outNum :: Int -> IO()
outNum i = Ex.catch (putStrLn(show (getNum i)))
           (\err -> putStrLn (show (err :: Ex.IOException)))
```

You can catch all exceptions by using `Ex.SomeException`. However, see
the commentary about doing this in the [Control.Exception docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:4)

To catch several different kinds of exceptions, see the [`catches` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:catches)

**Update**

Another way to indicate the type of exception you are interested in
is to define the handler as a named function and provide a "normal"
type signature:

```
outNum i = Ex.catch (putStrLn (show (getNum i))
            handler
  where handler :: Ex.IOException -> IO ()
        handler err = putStrLn $ "caught: " ++ show err
```

and often you will see `catch` written as an infix operator:

```
outNum i = putStrLn (show (getNum i)) `catch` handler
```

Finally, with ScopedTypeVariables you can put the type annotation
on the lambda's argument:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

outNum i = putStrLn ...
             `catch` (\(err :: Ex.SomeException) -> putStrLn ("caught: " ++ show err))
```

Comment: Aaah, I see. I actually wasn't aware that I could add a type constraint like that, which is really useful to know when working with lambdas. Is there a name for that specific syntax construct?

Comment: I just call it a type annotation, and you can annotate any subexpression. I've updated the answer with some additional ways of providing the type information to GHC in the catch call.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I really appreciate the added detail, you've been a great help.